# MySQL autoincrement column jumps by 10- why?

Tags: mysql

I have a couple tables in which I created an object ID as either an Int or Bigint, and in both cases, they seem to autoincrement by 10 (ie, the first insert is object ID 1, the second is object ID 11, the third is object ID 21, etc).  Two questions:

1. Why does it do that?
2. Is that a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem, although it might indicate the wish to have the ability to insert values in between the others and thus relying on the id as ordering criteria. That's not good.

Comment: It could also be a problem if you worried about running out of ID too fast (if you expect LOTS of records), since you're only using 1/10 of the range you have storage for.

Comment: I'd guess that your auto_increment_increment is set to something else than 1 because of replication. With replicated tables one cannot use 1 because of potential key collisions.

Answer (score 57):

Please do not change the `auto_increment_increment`. ClearDB is doing this on purpose. It's explained in [the documentation](https://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#general_16):

> ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL
>   support. As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or
>   sequences) must be configured in order for one master not to use the
>   same key as the other, in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL
>   to skip certain keys, and by enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset
>   for each key used. The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is
>   for future development.

Comment: great. This helps me alot. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't *technically* answer the question, but very helpful information nonetheless.

Comment: This answer should be combined with the accepted answer, its just as important as the currently accepted explanation.

Answer (score 49):

Check to see the seed value of the autoincrement isn't set to 10.

You can check by:

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='the_table_you_want';
```

As noted elsewhere you can change by using the system variable @@set_auto_increment_increment

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

If you want to start the values at a number other than one you can go:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Comment: Oh, I found my problem- it's how auto_increment_increment is set.  thanks!

Comment: HQ says no dice on changing it, and MySQL docs say it can't be altered on a per-table basis.  So I guess I'll have to live with an upper limit of 1.8 quintillion IDs rather than 18.4 quintillion.

Comment: Your first select statement seems to show what the next value in the sequence is, not how much it increments by.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks @Jim Fiorato for providing the link.

To check how much the auto increment value increments by, use the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';

+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 4     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 8):

The auto increment increment value is set in the MySQL system variables.

See here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#option_mysqld_auto-increment-increment

Answer (score 1):

autoincriment value can jump if using insert with IGNORE attribute in case when record was not created

```
insert IGNORE into my_table set column=1
```