# MySQL's auto_increment not incrementing by 1

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want auto_increment to increment by 1 each time I insert a row. It doesn't matter if I later delete a row in the middle, I always want it to increment by 1.

The problem is that MySQL keeps incrementing by 10. It goes from 1 to 11, to etc.

I've adjusted auto_increment, auto_increment_increment, auto_increment_offset, with no avail by setting them to 1 or 0 where appropriate.

EDIT:

These were the actions:

`SET @@auto_increment_offset=1`

`ALTER TABLE posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 0` or 1

`SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;`

Also, i am using the MYISAM engine for this particular table,
though it appears to be happening to another table without that engine.
The reason i am using MYISAM is because it allows for auto-inc on multiple indexes.

And i can't restart my db because it's running on a shared server on heroku.
I also don't understand how this is a duplicate if it hasn't been resolved elsewhere.

Comment: What platform are you on? This is highly unusual behavior.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why 

Also, have you tried changing those settings in the configuration, and then restarting the MySQL service? Not just a restart, but a complete `service mysqld stop` and `service mysqld start`?

Comment: Tip: when you search the internet, add "mysql" and your server version to the search terms, so you can get results from the MySQL manual, e.g.: [mysql 5.5 autoincrement](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+5.5+autoincrement).

Comment: Where did you adjust those numbers? CNF file or?

Comment: Good question, but please try to keep titles functional - titles are simply a relevant summary to encourage people to click on your question. See my edit.

Comment: Please can you show your sql and results