# change auto_increment value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I want to change auto_increment value in mysql. Right now it's 10.
I have gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why) in stackoverflow.

I tried with

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

But when I checked that variable by show variable command then my result was like,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';

+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

I am running my server on windows azure. Is that any problem with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Try executing this

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment =1;
```

You can also set it on table level

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: ERROR: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

Comment: The second one adjusts the initial sequence, not the increment increment.

Comment: Setting globals requires administrator access.

Comment: is there any option in windows azure to do this?

Comment: I tried it with alter table too. but it's still incrementing by 10.

Comment: When you execute `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` , does it say also 10?
`