# how to increase the autoincrement by 7 in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL server
In my database, I want to add a number for every user automatically, I want it to be increased by 7 numbers each time.
how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL autoincrement column jumps by 10- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why)

Comment: There is no such feature in MySQL.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Is this an autoincrement column, that should increase with each new row in a table? Please add more detail to your question.